# multiple if in a shorthand and in an compact way

Tags: java

can you help me organize the if else statement below in a more compact way?

```
if (abciden != null ) {
    PERFORM SSS
}

if (abciden == null
        && subject
                .equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_ert)) {
    //PERFORM CCC
}

if (abciden == null
        && subject
                .equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_fgt)) {
    //PERFORM BBB
}
```

please advise me on how to compact these conditions want to replace if with shorthand conditional ternary operator ? :

Comment: There's no `if-else` statement here. There are 3 stand-alone `if` statements.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `else`:

```
if (abciden != null) {
    // PERFORM SSS
}
else {
    if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_ert)) {
        //PERFORM CCC
    }
    if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_fgt)) {
        //PERFORM BBB
    }
}
```

Or as I'm assuming `subject` cannot match both constants:

```
if (abciden != null) {
    // PERFORM SSS
}
else if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_ert)) {
     //PERFORM CCC
}
else if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_fgt)) {
     //PERFORM BBB
}
```

---

Re your edit:

> want to replace if with shorthand conditional ternary operator ? :

Okay, if you *specifically* want the ternary, then ensure that whatever these "perform" steps are, they return a value. Then you could use this monstrosity:

```
rv = abciden != null ? performSSS() : subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_ert) ? performCCC() : subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_fgt) ? performCCC() : didNothingValue;
```

I. Do. Not. Recommend. It. :-) Hard to read, hard to debug, hard to maintain.

Comment: looking some compact version using shorthand operators

Comment: I don't think that shorthand operators can help you here. I don't see any way to further shorten it.

Comment: That's the only way to write the logic for your requirement. What more short you want?

Comment: I prefer to write few more lines but cleaner. That's why I avoid the ternary operator.

Comment: I think the second version with the && perform...() is a realy bad idea. It makes the code less readable and much more error prone.

Comment: @Casey: I completely agree. **And** it doesn't work in Java, so I removed it. :-) (I was a bit surprised by that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (abciden != null ) {
    // PERFORM SSS
}
else {
    if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_ert)) {
        //PERFORM CCC
    }
    else if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase(IOAConstants.DDD_REPORT_SUBJECT_fgt)) {
        //PERFORM BBB
    }
}
```

Slightly modified @T.J. code :p

Comment: That changes the logic. In the original code both of the "inner"-ifs can run, in your version just one.

Comment: @Casey: Only if these constants have the identical value (case independent) :)

Comment: It's quite impossible "subject" can be both looking at the requirement.